# Menu Dropdown and color palette (theme color) questions

Tags: website-design, css, html5

I have been able to create my own drop down menu. I moved it from being HTML / CSS to using jQuery to help, so that the menu drop down stayed when its parent element was hovered over.

-> My biggest thing is I want the drop down to drop directly below the main item and be centered to it. Right now, I only have it positioned below the parent element using the "left" and "top" property.

I could then alter how the drop down looks from there, unless anyone would have any ideas on what would make it look good. It's pretty dismal right  now, unfortunately. I.E., I'm not sure what would make a good looking drop down menu.

Current site looks:
http://www.mysticdev.com/

Comment: Hi @Tyler!  Welcome to the site.  At the moment, your post appears to be asking three separate questions.  For a Q&A site like this, it's better to just ask one per post.  Can you pick one of the questions and explain what your thinking about it so far has been and what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: That should be a little bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use pure css for dropdown menu. You can easily adjust into css only. [Here is the tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu). Hope it helps you :)

Comment: You can of course use pure CSS, but there is nothing wrong with enhancing it further with jQuery or normal Javascript.